# Ordering by meta_value AND date NOT WORKING with wp_query

Tags: wp-query, order, date, meta-value

I want to select posts and custom post type with a specific meta value (mb_home!=0), of last week and ORDER them by mb_home. If they have the same mb_home value, I want them to be ordered by date. Both order have to be DESC.

I am using this query but it just does not work:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => array ('post', 'aggregato'),
            'posts_per_page' => 13,
            'post__not_in' => $linked_posts,
            'meta_key' => 'mb_home',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                        'key' => 'mb_home',
                                        'value' => '0',
                                        'compare' => '>',
                                    )
                            ),
            'date_query' => array(
                                    'after' => '1 week ago',
                            )
            ));
```

If I drop `date` and use `'order by' => 'meta_value_num'` the query gives me back the results correctly ordered by mb_home DESC. But if they have the same mb_home value, they are ordered by date ASC.

If I try to change the way I order stuff, using this syntax:

```
'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' ),
```

instead of the above orderby and order statements, it just falls back to date DESC ignoring completely the mb_home value.

All these results are the same with `meta_value` instead of `meta_value_num`. Nothing changes.

Please, give me some pointers, because I've been over this for almost a month, trying everything but not succeeding.

Oh masters of wordpress! I invoke your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `posts_orderby` filter to do this at the mo, eg

```
function wpse159469_posts_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
    return implode( ' DESC,', explode( ',', str_replace( array(' ASC', ' DESC' ), '', $orderby ) ) ) . ' DESC';
}
```

then around your query:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse159469_posts_orderby', 10, 2 );
$query = new WP_Query( array( // etc
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse159469_posts_orderby', 10 );
```

Comment: YES! Oh my God, YES! It works!!! Oh bonger I love you. Thank you thank you thank you.

Just out of curiosity, what's the theory behind this solution?

Comment: WP_Query fires a lot of filters before doing the actual query, `posts_where`, `posts_groupby`, `posts_clauses`, etc which can be used to manipulate the sql generated - originally intended according to the source for paging and caching manipulation but very useful generally to do specialist stuff or work-arounds. In this case as you want DESC order the filter just blindly deletes any ordering and appends DESC to each comma-separated orderby field.